# cannot read from QUdpSocket client

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qudpsocket

I send command to a system and read response from it. My machine is client, I write a packet successfully to server, however, I cannot receive the response from it. I am wondering why this happens, please have a look at my code: (server address is 192.168.100.143 and the port is 11000)

```
void UDP::UDPInit(int port)
{
    socketPort = port;

    udpsocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
}


void UDP::sendCommand(QByteArray data)
{
    QHostAddress *host  = new QHostAddress("192.168.100.143");
    quint16 port = 11000;
    if(udpsocket->writeDatagram(data.data(),QHostAddress(ip),socketPort)==-1)
        emit clientLogMessage(QString("UDPCLIENT : Write problem !"));
    else
        udpsocket->flush();

    while (!udpsocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
         QByteArray datagram;
         datagram.resize(udpsocket->pendingDatagramSize());
         qDebug() << udpsocket->pendingDatagramSize();
         udpsocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), host, &port);
         emit dataReceived(datagram);
     }
}
```

Comment: if you are in a event loop then just connect to the `readyRead()` signal of udpsocket instead of that while loop

Comment: May I ask the difference?

Comment: returning to the even loop and not dealing with the bugs that I see in the loop

Comment: You have a memory leak in there. `QHostAddress *host  = new QHostAddress("192.168.100.143");`. There is no reason for using a pointer there. You should create it like this: `QHostAddress host("192.168.100.143");`

Comment: I tested the program, bind still returns false!, I wonder why this happens!

Comment: I think you will have to call `bind()` and bind your `QUdpSocket` object to an address, if you want to listen for datagrams. `bind()` returns true if it was successfully bound, remember to check that.

Answer (score 2):

QUdpSocket has a signal readyRead which is emitted each time a new packet is available, if you are in an event loop I suggest you use it

the condition in your while is negated which means that `udpsocket->pendingDatagramSize()` will return -1 inside the while loop and `readDatagram` will discard the packet

fixed code:

```
void UDP::UDPInit(int port)
{
    socketPort = port;

    udpsocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    connect(udpsocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readSocket()));
}


void UDP::sendCommand(QByteArray data)
{
    QHostAddress *host  = new QHostAddress("192.168.100.143");
    quint16 port = 11000;
    if(udpsocket->writeDatagram(data.data(),QHostAddress(ip),socketPort)==-1)
        emit clientLogMessage(QString("UDPCLIENT : Write problem !"));
    else
        udpsocket->flush();

}

void UDP::readSocket()
{
    while (udpsocket->hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
         QByteArray datagram;
         datagram.resize(udpsocket->pendingDatagramSize());
         qDebug() << udpsocket->pendingDatagramSize();
         udpsocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), host, &port);
         emit dataReceived(datagram);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. However, I do not still understand the difference between using signal and a simple while loop. both do the same thing apparently here.

Comment: no the while loop never actually waits until something is able to read unless you do `waitForReadyRead` but then you block the event thread and nothing else can be done on it

Comment: is it necessary to call bind() in this program? a fellow suggested this might be due to ignoring bind() and if I do that, I cannot read from server, though I can write to it successfully.

Comment: I tested the program, bind still returns false!, I wonder why this happens!